# Does a restful service client's concurrent requests cause problems to the restful service?

Tags: java, rest, futuretask

I am testing a Restful web service in Java through a client's http access. I have a big file of text and for each line of the file, I need to send a http request to the Web service to process the text and get the result back to the client. To speed up the processing, I tried to use a multi-thread application to send HTTP requests concurrently to the Web service.

It seems that when I set the thread count=1 in client's code, the service works well but the speed is slow. When I set the thread count>1, the web service's log displayed some error message, i.e. "timeout" (in certain places I have timeout monitoring code) or "executionexception" or interruptedexception". In the Web service's code, there are Future objects used.

My question is:

```
1) Does the client's concurrency affect the web service's thread safety? I thought it won't and shouldn't. 
2) What are the possible reasons for generating those error messages?
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Multithreated clients do not affect thread safety of the server. But they might reveal threading problems on the server (if the server is not threadsafe).

2) Standard threading problems can cause this. Especially race conditions and deadlocks. Without the code it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: "But they might reveal threading problems on the server"? if clients do not affect thread safety?

Comment: It is a bit nitpicky, but a server is threadsafe or it is not threadsafe. That does not depend on how many clients access it concurrently.

Comment: But it looks like when a lot of requests at the same time are made to the server, the server got a problem; otherwise (single thread with few requests), it runs well.